# Undefined Symbol errors when using LLVM on OS X

Tags: c++, llvm

I cannot get LLVM to work on my system. My knowledge on GCC and what kinds of flags to pass is and on makefiles is very limited, if someone could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

I'm on OSX and installed LLVM using homebrew. The symbols that GCC cannot find all exist on my system, but for some reason it's unable to find it.

This is the file that I try to compile using the makefile below:

```
// STL 
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

// LLVM 
#include <llvm/Pass.h>
#include <llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Function.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Instruction.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Instructions.h>
#include <llvm/IR/CFG.h>
#include <llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h>
#include <llvm/IR/InstIterator.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Constants.h>

// For older versions of llvm you may have to include instead:
// #include "llvm/Support/CFG.h"
// #include <llvm/Support/InstIterator.h>

using namespace llvm;

namespace {

class DefinitionPass  : public FunctionPass {
public:
    static char ID;
    DefinitionPass() : FunctionPass(ID) {}

    virtual void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &au) const {
        au.setPreservesAll();
    }

    virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F) {
            // TODO
            errs() << "def-pass\n";
        return false;
    }
};

class FixingPass : public FunctionPass {
public:
    static char ID;
    FixingPass() : FunctionPass(ID){}

    virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F){
            // TODO
            errs() << "fix-pass\n";
        return true;
    }
};
} // namespace


char DefinitionPass::ID = 0;
char FixingPass::ID = 1;

// Pass registrations
static RegisterPass<DefinitionPass> X("def-pass", "Reaching definitions pass");
static RegisterPass<FixingPass> Y("fix-pass", "Fixing initialization pass");
```

Make file:

```
CXXFLAGS = -rdynamic $(shell llvm-config --cxxflags) -g -O0 -std=c++0x

all: p34.so

%.so: %.o 
  $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -dylib -shared -fPIC  $^ -o $@

clean:
  rm -f *.o *~ *.so
```

The rdynamic option is ignored for some reason.

llvm-config --cxxflags yields the following on my system:

```
-I/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/9.0.0_1/include -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++   -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
```

This is the error message that I get:

```
c++ -rdynamic -I/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/9.0.0_1/include -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++   -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -g -O0 -std=c++0x -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include  -c -o p34.o p34.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
c++ -rdynamic -I/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/9.0.0_1/include -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++   -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -g -O0 -std=c++0x -dylib -shared -fPIC  p34.o -o p34.so
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "llvm::raw_ostream::write(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      llvm::raw_ostream::operator<<(llvm::StringRef) in p34.o
  "llvm::FunctionPass::assignPassManager(llvm::PMStack&, llvm::PassManagerType)", referenced from:
      vtable for (anonymous namespace)::DefinitionPass in p34.o
      vtable for (anonymous namespace)::FixingPass in p34.o
  "llvm::PassRegistry::registerPass(llvm::PassInfo const&, bool)", referenced from:
      llvm::RegisterPass<(anonymous namespace)::DefinitionPass>::RegisterPass(llvm::StringRef, llvm::StringRef, bool, bool) in p34.o
      llvm::RegisterPass<(anonymous namespace)::FixingPass>::RegisterPass(llvm::StringRef, llvm::StringRef, bool, bool) in p34.o
  "llvm::PassRegistry::getPassRegistry()", referenced from:
      llvm::RegisterPass<(anonymous namespace)::DefinitionPass>::RegisterPass(llvm::StringRef, llvm::StringRef, bool, bool) in p34.o
      llvm::RegisterPass<(anonymous namespace)::FixingPass>::RegisterPass(llvm::StringRef, llvm::StringRef, bool, bool) in p34.o
  "llvm::DisableABIBreakingChecks", referenced from:
      llvm::VerifyDisableABIBreakingChecks in p34.o
  "llvm::Pass::releaseMemory()", referenced from:
      vtable for (anonymous namespace)::DefinitionPass in p34.o
      vtable for (anonymous namespace)::FixingPass in p34.o
  "llvm::Pass::dumpPassStructure(unsigned int)", referenced from:
      vtable for (anonymous namespace)::DefinitionPass in p34.o
      vtable for (anonymous namespace)::FixingPass in p34.o
  "llvm::Pass::getAsImmutablePass()", referenced from:
      vtable for (anonymous namespace)::DefinitionPass in p34.o
      vtable for (anonymous namespace)::FixingPass in p34.o
  "llvm::Pass::getAsPMDataManager()", referenced from:
      vtable for (anonymous namespace)::DefinitionPass in p34.o
      vtable for (anonymous namespace)::FixingPass in p34.o
  "llvm::Pass::preparePassManager(llvm::PMStack&)", referenced from:
      vtable for (anonymous namespace)::DefinitionPass in p34.o
      vtable for (anonymous namespace)::FixingPass in p34.o
  "llvm::Pass::getAdjustedAnalysisPointer(void const*)", referenced from:
      vtable for (anonymous namespace)::DefinitionPass in p34.o
      vtable for (anonymous namespace)::FixingPass in p34.o
  "llvm::Pass::~Pass()", referenced from:
      llvm::FunctionPass::~FunctionPass() in p34.o
  "llvm::errs()", referenced from:
      (anonymous namespace)::DefinitionPass::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) in p34.o
      (anonymous namespace)::FixingPass::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) in p34.o
  "llvm::FunctionPass::createPrinterPass(llvm::raw_ostream&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) const", referenced from:
      vtable for (anonymous namespace)::DefinitionPass in p34.o
      vtable for (anonymous namespace)::FixingPass in p34.o
  "llvm::FunctionPass::getPotentialPassManagerType() const", referenced from:
      vtable for (anonymous namespace)::DefinitionPass in p34.o
      vtable for (anonymous namespace)::FixingPass in p34.o
  "llvm::Pass::getPassName() const", referenced from:
      vtable for (anonymous namespace)::DefinitionPass in p34.o
      vtable for (anonymous namespace)::FixingPass in p34.o
  "llvm::Pass::verifyAnalysis() const", referenced from:
      vtable for (anonymous namespace)::DefinitionPass in p34.o
      vtable for (anonymous namespace)::FixingPass in p34.o
  "llvm::Pass::getAnalysisUsage(llvm::AnalysisUsage&) const", referenced from:
      vtable for (anonymous namespace)::FixingPass in p34.o
  "llvm::Pass::print(llvm::raw_ostream&, llvm::Module const*) const", referenced from:
      vtable for (anonymous namespace)::DefinitionPass in p34.o
      vtable for (anonymous namespace)::FixingPass in p34.o
  "typeinfo for llvm::FunctionPass", referenced from:
      typeinfo for (anonymous namespace)::DefinitionPass in p34.o
      typeinfo for (anonymous namespace)::FixingPass in p34.o
  "vtable for llvm::FunctionPass", referenced from:
      llvm::FunctionPass::FunctionPass(char&) in p34.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for llvm::Pass", referenced from:
      llvm::Pass::Pass(llvm::PassKind, char&) in p34.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [p34.so] Error 1
rm p34.o
```

Can someone tell me how to make GCC find those LLVM files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to grab the LLVM linker flags and libraries as well:

```
LDFLAGS += $(shell llvm-config --libs --ldflags)

%.so: %.o 
  $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -dylib -shared -fPIC  $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
```

Comment: Also `LDLIBS` perhaps?

Comment: It does not seem to contain anything useful by default, but it could be added for symmetry with the regular recipes, yes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The llvm symbols can now be found, but I get other undefined symbols errors: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_del_curterm", referenced from:
      llvm::sys::Process::FileDescriptorHasColors(int) in libLLVMSupport.a(Process.cpp.o)

Comment: And three similar ones. This seems to be related to the system libraries that the homebrew installed version of llvm uses. It seems to be related to a library called lcurses.

Comment: But since this is not related to the original question, I will probably open another question, unless you can also help me with this.

Comment: What is LDLIBS?

Comment: LDLIBS is a variable used when linking executables using the default recipe in Make.

Comment: As for your other problem, I think you can just add `-lcurses` to the `LDFLAGS` line.

Comment: Thx for this tip. It helped me solve the same issue when running LLVM Kaleidoscope tutorial, see https://gist.github.com/galderz/588cdb20c748250fe19a2872bf131e9f#file-gistfile1-txt-L14